# Twitter Status Object text ends in '...'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Whenever I pull tweets from the twitter they all end in [Tweet ending in '...'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQuYS.png) . I understand that there are such a thing as truncated tweets, but the API documentation does not specify how to retrieve the entire tweet and not just the 140 character limit

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

```
 auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
   consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

tweets = []

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q='#vaccine').items(10):
    with open("tweets.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(status.text)
        file.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `tweet_mode="extended"` argument in your method.

```py
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q='#vaccine', tweet_mode="extended").items(10):
    print(status.full_text)
```

Please note that the text field will then be named `full_text` instead of `text`.

You can read more about that in the [Tweepy documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/extended_tweets.html).